# MikroTik LHGG LTE6 kit internet dropping and slower than with a cheap 4G router

Tags: networking, cellular-internet

I've bought a MikroTik LHGG LTE6 kit to boost reception for my home internet because the 4G connection where I live is quite unstable (and 4G is the only way to get internet here). However, compared with a standard router that comes with an internet subscription it made things worse. I've tried rotating the antenna through 360 degrees and adjusting so that the numbers are highest.

With my Huawei B535-232 (located indoors) the connection had the following numbers connected to the cell with id 36028167:
RSRQ -7dB
RSRP -100dBm
RSSI -73dBm
SINR 8dB

Now I'm getting number such as these, pointing the antenna westward towards one of the cell towers (this is where a neighbour's professionally installed LHG antenna is pointing). Note that the antenna is installed on the roof, whereas the Huawei router was indoors.

```
           pin-status: ok
  registration-status: registered
        functionality: full
         manufacturer: "MikroTik"
                model: "R11e-LTE6"
             revision: R11e-LTE6_V027
     current-operator: 24803
                  lac: 235
       current-cellid: 36028163
               enb-id: 140735
            sector-id: 3
           phy-cellid: 344
    access-technology: LTE (CA2)
       session-uptime: 5m1s
                 imei: XXX
                 imsi: XXX
                 uicc: XXX
         primary-band: B20@10Mhz earfcn: 6400 phy-cellid: 344
              ca-band: B1@20Mhz earfcn: 103 phy-cellid: 344
                 rssi: -69dBm
                 rsrp: -101dBm
                 rsrq: -12dB
                 sinr: 6dB
                  cqi: 8
                   ri: 2
```

And these numbers pointing it southward:

```
           pin-status: ok
  registration-status: registered
        functionality: full
         manufacturer: "MikroTik"
                model: "R11e-LTE6"
             revision: R11e-LTE6_V027
     current-operator: TELE2
                  lac: 235
       current-cellid: 36028163
               enb-id: 140735
            sector-id: 3
           phy-cellid: 344
    access-technology: LTE (CA2)
       session-uptime: 1m2s
                 imei: XXX
                 imsi: XXX
                 uicc: XXX
         primary-band: B20@10Mhz earfcn: 6400 phy-cellid: 344
              ca-band: B1@20Mhz earfcn: 103 phy-cellid: 344
                 rssi: -72dBm
                 rsrp: -105dBm
                 rsrq: -12dB
                 sinr: 3dB
                  cqi: 7
                   ri: 1
```

I'm not sure if that's related, but quite often the link goes fully down and network connection is lost. It comes up by itself after a minute or so.

```
# Down (2021-03-28 09:03:58)
[admin@MikroTik] /interface lte> info lte1 once
           pin-status: ok
  registration-status: not searching
        functionality: tx and rx rf circuit disabled
         manufacturer: "MikroTik"
                model: "R11e-LTE6"
             revision: R11e-LTE6_V027
       session-uptime: 28m36s
                 imei: XXX
                 imsi: XXX
                 uicc: XXX
# Down (2021-03-28 09:28:29):
[admin@MikroTik] /interface lte> info lte1 once
     pin-status: ok
  functionality: tx and rx rf circuit disabled
   manufacturer: "MikroTik"
          model: "R11e-LTE6"
       revision: R11e-LTE6_V027
           imei: XXX
           imsi: XXX
           uicc: XXX
```

And here's a bit more debugging info, if that helps:

```
[admin@MikroTik] > /interface lte scan lte1
Flags: C - current, A - available, F - forbidden
  OPERATOR                               MCC-MNC ACCESS-TECHNOLOGY                                    RSSI          RSRP          RSRQ
  Tele2 EE                                 24803 Evolved 3G (LTE)                                   -75dBm        -95dBm         -11dB
  Tele2 EE                                 24803 GSM compact
  Tele2 EE                                 24803 3G
  ELISA                                    24802 GSM compact
  Telia                                    24801 GSM compact
  Telia                                    24801 3G
  ELISA                                    24802 3G
  Telia                                    24801 Evolved 3G (LTE)
  ELISA                                    24802 Evolved 3G (LTE)

[admin@MikroTik] > /interface lte cell-monitor lte1 max-age=10
PHY-CELLID BAND          PSC EARFCN                   RSRP          RSRQ          RSSI         SINR          RSCP AGE
        17 B20               6400                  -110dBm       -19.5dB                                          8s
        84 B20               6400                  -111dBm       -19.5dB                                          2s
       344 B1                103                   -117dBm         -15dB                                          2s
       351 B20               6400                  -110dBm       -19.5dB                                          5s
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because I've heard that just replacing the regular router with the antenna has doubled their speed and increased stability. Am I missing something regarding the setup? I haven't connected the grounding wire – that can't be it, can it?

I'm now thinking of returning it (I have a week left for a no-questions-asked return) and would like to understand if it's me being dense or the antenna being defective. And whether I should get an identical model or go with an omnidirectional antenna such as Huawei B2368. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is hard for us to know how this might set up in your area for effective use (hard for me at any rate). Within the return period: ask the seller for technical setup support, then return it if that does not work. If returned, ask seller for a better unit.

Comment: I understand that my issue is quite circumstantial, but I was hoping to either confirm or deny that I'm doing everything correctly and not missing a crucial step required for gaining (no pun intended) maximum benefit from a directional antenna.